# Algebraic extension of an abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $H \leqslant G$ be abelian groups.  Suppose there were $k \gt 1$, $x \in G \setminus H$, such that $x^k = b \in H$.  Then Define $H(x) = \{h x^n : n \in \Bbb{Z}, h \in H\}$ to be a simple extension of $G$ obtained by adjoining $x$.  It is such that $H \leqslant H(x) \leqslant G$, and also $H(x)$ is an algebraic extension as each $h' \in H(x)$ is the root of some $x^m = b \in H$.  There's probably a lot more to be said.

Has anyone looked into algebraic extensions of just groups (not fields) and not the usual definition of group extension (having to do with exact sequences), but the one above, ie. "algebraic".

Thanks.

Comment: @Wilf yeah, that's it.

Comment: @Wilf for non-abelian groups the situation is more complex looking

Comment: @Wilf  What you're trying to say I think is that $\Bbb{R}^+(i)$ is not algebraic.  It equals all $a + b i$ such that $a \in \Bbb{R}$, $b \in \Bbb{Z}$, or $\Bbb{R}^+ + \Bbb{Z}^+i$ which is a direct sum of groups.  But that is an example of a non-algebraic extension as $i$ doesn't solve any $mx = b \in \Bbb{R}$.  It's a transcendental group extension of $\Bbb{R}^+$ but an algebraic one of $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$ so what you've proved is that there are algebraic elements for one of those groups that aren't for the other somewhat-related by the ring $\Bbb{R}$, group.