# Extending "the ring of exponents" from $\Bbb{Z}$ to that which contains a solution to $4^x - 3 = 0 \pmod 5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field, discrete-logarithms, integral-extensions

Let $R = \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers modulo $5$.  Then $4^x = 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, \dots$ as $x$ ranges over $\Bbb{Z}$.  Thus $4^x = 3$ and $4^x = 2$ have no solution $x \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Now, $R^{\times}$ the group in which the repeated multiplication resides (exponentiation) is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.  I'm wondering if there's a way to extend the ring of exponents $\Bbb{Z}$ formally to $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ where $x$ is the formal symbol devised so that $4^x = 3 \pmod 5$.  Similarly to the way in which $R(i) = \Bbb{C}$ and $i$ solves $x^2 + 1 = 0$. Here, we're wanting to solve $4^x - 3 = 0$ i.e. exponentiation instead of constant powering.

Is there a theory already developed for this case?

Is it even possible?  I.e. can we have a ring $S \geqslant \Bbb{Z}$ such that $4^x = 3$ has a solution in $S$?  And correspondingly an $S$-module that extends the $\Bbb{Z}$-module $R^{\times}$?

I want to somehow apply this to special cases of the discrete logarithm problem.  Since given a prime $p$, some solutions $a^x = b \pmod p$ do not exist, I would like to force them to exist, again similarly to the imaginary unit $i \in \Bbb{C}$.

---

Two related previous posts:

- [Can basic field theory be transposed over to group theory? (polynomials in a group-only setting)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962861/can-basic-field-theory-be-transposed-over-to-group-theory-polynomials-in-a-gro)
- [Algebraic extension of an abelian group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809377/algebraic-extension-of-an-abelian-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $R^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ via the map $f$ where $f(1)=0$, $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=3$, and $f(4)=2$.

Now, working with the additive group that we are more confortable with, the problem translates to asking whether there is an endomorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for which $\varphi(2)=3$. The answer is that there is no such endomorphism, for $\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)=\varphi(2)=3$, but the equation $a+a=3$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Back to the multiplicative group, the element $4$ is a square, but $3$ is not a square, so there is no endomorphism of the multiplicative group that sends $4$ to $3$. Hence, it is impossible to extend the ring of exponents to the polynomials over the integers in such a way that $4^x=3$.

Comment: I don't get your comment about needing an endomorphism.  Could you explain?

Comment: Okay, I am understanding your argument more.  But to answer your last remark.  $4^x = 3$, $2^{2x} = 3$ so $(2^x)^2 = 3$ is a square and its square root is $2^x \in S \setminus R$.  I.e. it likewise gets solved by introducing the solution $x$.   Such a thing happens in fields as well, e.g. $x^2 = -4$ has solution $2i$.